# How to display UTF-8 emoji characters in nano editor?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, emoji, nano

How do I display emojis (UTF-8) when I open a file using the nano editor? I can only see blank spaces where they should be appearing. When

I read in [ubuntu thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252645) a proposed solution saying you should check the character encoding of your terminal but when I try it  I only see the 'UTF-8' and 'Default UTF-8' options. But I don't think this solves anything for I  can see emojis being printed on terminal's screen when I concatenate the file.

Funnily enough, when I use multitail to see the same file in real-time, again from terminal, I see garbage instead of emojis.

My environment variables:

```
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LAN (none)
LC_ALL (none)
```

Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

I'm using Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Same problem here. I have a UTF-8 file that has emojis... when I view it with `less` (v551) I can see it fine. But `nano` (v4.5) displays a blank space where the emoji should be.